# Android: How to Simplify Implementation of Various Activities with Similar Layout

Tags: android

Recently I am writing an Android Apps to control some external devices. There are different kinds of device but they are very similar. Therefore the layout for each activity for controlling the device is also very similar. For example all layouts basically has the same textviews, editviews and buttons. The difference is one device has a listview but the others do not have it.

Now I just copy each layout (and the respective activity) for each device and change a few things in each activity. I feel it is kind of redundant and I think there must be another simpler/more efficient method to implement it, but how?

Thank you.

Comment: Implement a fragment for all the common tasks and implement 1 for the special case. Reuse these in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse common part of your layouts using tag include

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/example"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" />

...
```

in this case layout from **layout/example** wil be reused.

More details here:
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include

Comment: By this, seems I still need to copy the same part of code in each activity. For example: EditText exampleText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.edtExampleText);

Comment: Yes but then you can make different logic for the same layout.
If you have same logic and layout you can use fragments. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html